# Google's pagination class

Tags: php, pagination

I have got the Google pagination function, and it asks to pass in 4 arguments,

```
paginate($offset,$limit,$total,$base_url);
```

but its not working out for me.

I think I'm passing in the incorrect offset value.

how would I work out the offset value?

for the `$total` I just count the returned rows of the result set.

Comment: do you work at Google? I don't think you will be for long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Current page number - 1) x limit = offset

```
Page 1 x a limit of 10 = offset 0
Page 2 x a limit of 10 = offset 10
etc.
```